# How to check if an interface extends another in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

The [Type.IsSubclassOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) method only works with two concrete types, e.g.

```
public class A {}
public class B : A {}
typeof(B).IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)) // returns true
```

Is there a way to find out if an interface extends another? e.g.

```
public interface IA {}
public interface IB : IA {}
```

The only thing I can think of is to use GetInterfaces on IB and check if it contains IA, does anyone know of another/better way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
bool isAssignable = typeof(IA).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IB));
```

which gives you the information you need in this case I guess, but also of course works not only for interfaces.

I assume you have `Type` objects, if you have actual instances, this is shorter, clearer and more performant:

```
public interface ICar : IVehicle { /**/ }

ICar myCar = GetSomeCar();
bool isVehicle = myCar is IVehicle;
```

Answer (score 1):

`IsAssignableFrom` is what you are looking for. It's the equivalent of the `is` operator but with runtime values as types.

Examples:

```
// Does IDerivedInterface implements IBaseInterface ?
bool yes = typeof(IBaseInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IDerivedInterface));

// Does instance implements IBaseInterface ?
bool yes = typeof(IBaseInterface).IsAssignableFrom(instance.GetType());
```